# Python 3.6 adjacency Matrix: How to obtain it in a better way

Tags: python-3.x, adjacency-matrix

The problem starts with a classical csv file. An example can be:

date;origing;destiny;minutes;distance
19-02-2020;A;B;36;4
20-02-2020;A;B;33;4
24-02-2020;B;A;37;4
25-02-2020;A;C;20;7
27-02-2020;C;B;20;3
28-02-2020;A;B;37.2;4
28-02-2020;A;Z;44;10

My first idea consist in solving it in a classical programmaing way:

Loop + counter variables and represent de counter variables in a matrix like:
A B C Z
A  0 3 1 1
B  1 0 0 0
C  0 1 0 0
Z  0 0 0 0

My first question is if there is a better automatic way of implementing this in python instead os use classical programming algorithm based on loops and counters.

and what about obtaining more complex adjacence matrixes like the one that give you for example and average of times in the values?

Answer (score 0):

There are packages like `networkx`, but you could use the groupby of pandas.

I don't think pandas with groupby is the fastest. I think `networkx` would be faster, but at least groupby is better than a loop (is my guess).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

M = pd.read_csv('../sample_data.csv', sep=';')
M['constant'] = 1
print(M)
```

```
         date origing destiny  minutes  distance  constant
0  19-02-2020       A       B     36.0         4         1
1  20-02-2020       A       B     33.0         4         1
2  24-02-2020       B       A     37.0         4         1
3  25-02-2020       A       C     20.0         7         1
4  27-02-2020       C       B     20.0         3         1
5  28-02-2020       A       B     37.2         4         1
6  28-02-2020       A       Z     44.0        10         1
```

With groupby we can get counts;

```
counts = M.groupby(['origing','destiny']).count()[['constant']]
counts
```

```
                 constant
origing destiny          
A       B               3
        C               1
        Z               1
B       A               1
C       B               1
```

And store those values in a zero matrix

```
def key_map(key):
    a,b = key
    return (ord(a) - ord('A'),ord(b)-ord('A'))
```

will get the indicis, like

```
counts['constant'].keys().map(key_map).values
```

and we set those indicis to any values, i do the counts here, but you can use the same groupby to aggregate sum,average, or anything from other columns;

```
indici =  np.array( [tuple(x) for x in counts['constant'].keys().map(key_map).values] )
indici = tuple(zip(*indici))
```

and store with

```
Z = np.zeros((26,26))
Z[ indici ] = counts['constant']
```

I only print first few with

```
print(Z[:3,:3])
```

```
[[0. 3. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Nice approach. I should check excutiontime then.